# Spaces shouldn't be counted to string length

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops

This code gets user input then 256 % length of string is used. If the result is 3 and the input is abc the output is bcd. This works fine. However if the input is for example "hey whatsup" the length is 11 and it should be 10 because the space shouldn't be included for the length.

How can I programm this code so it dosen't count space to the length?

Is it even possible to implement it while using fgets?

Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

  int main() {

    char array[20];
    int length = 0;
    int i;
    int key = 256;

    printf("input:  ");

    fgets(array, 20, stdin);

    length = strlen(array) - 1;

    key = key % length;

    if (key > 0) {

      for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        if (array[i] == ' ') {

          printf("%c", array[i]);

          continue;

        }
        array[i] = array[i] + key;

        printf("%c", array[i]);
      }

    }

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: you could strip the spaces out first?

Comment: but I still want to print them

Comment: you could count the spaces then subtract that from the length?

Comment: Then you need a separate loop to count the number of spaces, and subtract it in the calculation of `key`.

Comment: By the way, `array[i] + key` could lead to arithmetic overflow. And depending on if the type `char` is signed or unsigned (which is implementation defined) that could lead to *undefined behavior*. It could also lead to the value of `array[i]` to become unprintable.

Comment: Minor: Code should avoid `key = key % length;` when `length==0`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How does `array[i] + key` lead to arithmetic overflow. and UB?  Worse case sums are in the range of [-a_few_100 ... +a_few_100].  Or are you concerned about `CHAR_BIT > 8`?

Comment: @chux You're right, there won't be any arithmetic overflow since `array[i]` will undergo usual arithmetic conversion and be promoted to an `int`. However, the result might be larger than `127` which will be truncated when assigned back to `array[i]` if `char` is signed (IIRC).

Comment: Fun fact: `if (array[i] == ' ')printf("%c", array[i]);` can be optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If you don't want to include the spaces in the calculation of the key, you have to make your own function to calculate the number of spaces.

2) The code `length = strlen(array) - 1;` seems to "take care" of a `'\n'` in the end of the string. However, you can't be sure that there is a `'\n'`. You need to check for that first.

3) Doing `key % 0` will be "bad" so check for that as well

The code could look something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int cnt_spaces(char* arr)
{
    int res = 0;
    while(*arr)
    {
        if (*arr == ' ')
        {
            ++res;
        }
        ++arr;
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    char array[20];
    int length = 0;
    int i;
    int key = 256;

    printf("input:  ");

    fgets(array, 20, stdin);
    length = strlen(array);
    if (strlen(array) == 0) return 0;  // or add error handling

    // Remove \n if present
    if (array[length-1] == '\n')
    {
        array[length-1] = '\0';
        --length;
    }
    printf("len = %d\n", length);

    int spaces = cnt_spaces(array);
    printf("spaces = %d\n", spaces);

    if (length == spaces) return 0;  // or add error handling
    key = key % (length - spaces);

    printf("key = %d\n", key);

    if (key > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (array[i] != ' ') {
                array[i] = array[i] + key;
            }
            printf("%c", array[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

Example:

```
input:  a b c
len = 5
spaces = 2
key = 1
b c d
```

Comment: If you're going to iterate through every character in a string checking to see if each one is a space, why would you also call `strlen`?

Comment: thanks I have tried it and it works however if I increase the array size to 100 and the input has 26 characters it counts the space as a character. so length is 27. I have been trying to fix it but can't find the solution

Comment: @TimRandall The length including spaces are still need for the loop that prints the result. The code be probably be rewritten for better performance but I prefer to keep it as close to OPs orginal code as possible.

Comment: @momonosuke What is the exact input in the case where you observe that?

Comment: notverysecure thiscaeserwas. when i type this i get unprintable chracters

Comment: @momonosuke Well... yes, you get unprintable characters - that true - but there is nothing wrong with the length calculation or the calculation of spaces. See https://ideone.com/8XaaSG

Comment: @momonosuke The reason you get unprintable characters is that the key will be 22 and when you add 22 to 'w' (which is 119) you be above the normal range of printable characters (which up to 127). See https://www.google.com/search?q=ascii+table&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjavpfGlYnfAhUI2SwKHZJ0D9UQsAR6BAgAEAE&biw=1920&bih=963#imgrc=8TZS0UxreQ2XgM: This is a general problem with your algorithm - it's not related to bugs in the implementation

Comment: yeah I just realized it now ,i tried adding an if clause like"  if(array[i]>'z'){
    array[i]=array[i]-'z'+'a'-1;
   }"                                                             but it only works for z

Comment: @momonosuke well, you can't really do much about it. The algorithm (i.e. just adding `key` to the input) will always result in non-printable values. Just consider `'~'` (which is 126). What can be added so that you still have a printable character?

Comment: 98 so i can get back to 'a' which has ascii value '97'